# Importing a CSV file into a PostgreSQL DB using Python-Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, etl, pygrametl

**Note:** Scroll down to the *Background* section for useful details. Assume the project uses Python-Django and South, in the following illustration.

**What's the best way to import the following CSV**

```
"john","doe","savings","personal"
"john","doe","savings","business"
"john","doe","checking","personal"
"john","doe","checking","business"
"jemma","donut","checking","personal"
```

**Into a PostgreSQL database with the related tables *Person*, *Account*, and *AccountType* considering:**

1. Admin users can change the database model and CSV import-representation in real-time via a custom UI
2. The saved CSV-to-Database table/field mappings are used when regular users import CSV files

**So far two approaches have been considered**

1. *ETL-API Approach*: Providing an ETL API a spreadsheet, my CSV-to-Database table/field mappings, and connection info to the target database. The API would then load the spreadsheet and populate the target database tables. Looking at pygrametl I don't think what i'm aiming for is possible. In fact, i'm not sure any ETL APIs do this.
2. *Row-level Insert Approach*: Parsing the CSV-to-Database table/field mappings, parsing the spreadsheet, and generating SQL inserts in "join-order".

**I implemented the second approach but am struggling with algorithm defects and code complexity. Is there a python ETL API out there that does what I want? Or an approach that doesn't involve reinventing the wheel?**

---

**Background**

The company I work at is looking to move hundreds of project-specific design spreadsheets hosted in sharepoint into databases. We're near completing a web application that meets the need by allowing an administrator to define/model a database for each project, store spreadsheets in it, and define the browse experience. At this stage of completion transitioning to a commercial tool isn't an option. Think of the web application as a django-admin alternative, though it isn't, with a DB modeling UI, CSV import/export functionality, customizable browse, and modularized code to address project-specific customizations.

The implemented CSV import interface is cumbersome and buggy so i'm trying to get feedback and find alternate approaches.

Comment: I think you should concretise the question. Extract a minimal example that you are looking for and post it. That is, write a csv sample data and normalized required target schema.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Hopefully this gets more attention. Changing the title now btw.

Comment: The question still makes no sense.  Design a schema, put it there, use it  -- which is a three-liner and/or a `psql` call.

Comment: This isn't a 3-liner, it's an enterprise web application for a fortune-500 company. The schema is dynamic to suit business needs, it did not start off that way, only administrators can change it via a UI. The CSV import solution is involved because the schema is dynamic, there's no getting around that. The code you provided made use of a static schema and didn't contain CSV import code. If you have suggestions on how to clarify the question i'd be glad to incorporate them.

Comment: It worries me that you don't have any sort of concrete/unique identifiers so far.  are the first 2 fields in these 2 examples illustrating the same person, or different people, or unknown ? `"john","doe","savings","personal"`,
`"john","doe","savings","business"`

Comment: It's only an illustration, so just assume uniqueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking a few steps back to address this problem per Occam's razor using updatable SQL views. It meant a few sacrifices:

1. Removing: South.DB-dependent real-time schema administration API, dynamic model loading, and dynamic ORM syncing
2. Defining models.py and an initial south migration by hand.

This allows for a simple approach to importing flat datasets (CSV/Excel) into a normalized database:

1. Define unmanaged models in models.py for each spreadsheet
2. Map those to updatable SQL Views (INSERT/UPDATE-INSTEAD SQL RULEs) in the initial south migration that adhere to the spreadsheet field layout
3. Iterating through the CSV/Excel spreadsheet rows and performing an `INSERT INTO <VIEW> (<COLUMNS>) VALUES (<CSV-ROW-FIELDS>);`

Answer (score 2):

How about separating the problem into two separate problems?

Create a `Person` class which represents a person in the database. This could use Django's ORM, or extend it, or you could do it yourself.

Now you have two issues:

1. Create a `Person` instance from a row in the CSV.
2. Save a `Person` instance to the database.

Now, instead of just CSV-to-Database, you have CSV-to-Person and Person-to-Database. I think this is conceptually cleaner. When the admins change the schema, that changes the Person-to-Database side. When the admins change the CSV format, they're changing the CSV-to-Database side. Now you can deal with each separately.

Does that help any?

Comment: Person would be one of many dynamically created objects since the entire model is dynamic; not just fields, tables too. Since every object is an instance, and objects are hierarchically related, persistence would demand row-level inserts at every "step" down the tree. This is definitely worth considering, and remains very similar to the row-level-insert approach.

Comment: Wish I could up the bounty to 100 to give better incentive

Comment: Why do you have the requirement that admins can completely change the schema? Maybe knowing that will help me think of something.

Comment: The web application substitutes a sharepoint repository that maintains a large quantity of excel spreadsheets with business-driven project data. The application originally tracked a single project. That project and the spreadsheets used changed over time requiring dynamic field support. As scope grew to include other projects it became apparent that the right solution was a model agnostic tool with modularized project logic. In short, the app is proprietary database modeling tool, with import, browse, export, and search interfaces; and modularized project-specific "business-logic".

Comment: How are the current dynamic models actually being used in the code that requires them? Do they run custom SQL queries and update those whenever an admin changes the schema? Do they operate on .csv files directly and change their code when those .csv files change? Do they have an ORM which they have to somehow update whenever the model changes?

Comment: The custom schema administration UI is used to create, modify, and commit changes to the loaded models and underlying database via South. The models are loaded dynamically by introspecting the database. So the database dictates the models loaded; Models.py no longer syncs the database since it's always in sync with it, all the while I have access to the ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I write import sub-systems almost every month at work, and as I do that kind of tasks to much I wrote sometime ago django-data-importer. This importer works like a django form and has readers for CSV, XLS and XLSX files that give you lists of dicts.

With data_importer readers you can read file to lists of dicts, iter on it with a for and save lines do DB.
With importer you can do same, but with bonus of validate each field of line, log errors and actions, and save it at end.

Please, take a look at https://github.com/chronossc/django-data-importer. I'm pretty sure that it will solve your problem and will help you with process of any kind of csv file from now :)

To solve your problem I suggest use data-importer with celery tasks. You upload the file and fire import task via a simple interface. Celery task will send file to importer and you can validate lines, save it, log errors for it. With some effort you can even present progress of task for users that uploaded the sheet.

Comment: The problem I need to solve is how to intelligently commit an entire CSV dataset to the database based on a mapping that defines the table each field belongs to and how those tables are related. Your importer could contribute towards a cleaner implementation of the _Row level insert approach_.

Comment: Importer maybe not help at this point because it expects a defined range of fields, but data_importer.readers will help. Since it save some code returning each line as a dict, you can have yourself a dict like {'fieldname': <function>, ...} and in a loop over dict itens call functions_dict[fieldname](fieldvalue, row). That function do the job of save on right place, here is a example: https://gist.github.com/chronossc/5208763

You can improve it with functions doing only value attribution to instances and after all saving instances.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that I found on github. Basically it detects the schema and allows overrides. Its whole goal is to just generate raw sql to be executed by psql and or whatever driver.

https://github.com/nmccready/csv2psql

```
  % python setup.py install
  % csv2psql --schema=public --key=student_id,class_id example/enrolled.csv > enrolled.sql
  % psql -f enrolled.sql
```

There are also a bunch of options for doing alters (creating primary keys from many existing cols) and merging  / dumps.